# Pull existing remote repo into empty repo in Hg

Tags: version-control, mercurial

```
mkdir test_remote
cd test_remote
hg init
hg pull existing_remote_repo (bitbucket, ssh, etc)
```

Is it a bad thing? Any potential dangers when I start pushing the changes from test_remote? Will there be head difference,generate different changeset, whatever it is?

Doing this way, is it the equivalence of `hg clone`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's equivalent to `hg clone`. No, there won't be any problems.

Comment: Correct. The extra work done by `hg clone` is 1) is writes a `.hg/hgrc` file with a default path, and 2) is will hardlink the clones when the source is on a local file system.

Comment: Thanks guys. I just found this a while ago. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6944981/is-hg-clone-equivalent-to-hg-initpull  :)